# Need to create an xml file (R.anim) that defines a pendulous movement in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

I would not like to reinvent the wheel (or the pendulum) here.

I have found samples of xml code to perform most of the animations in my project.
Examples (from  https://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/ )

slide_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.0" />

</set>
```

bounce.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator">

    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />

</set>
```

etc...

I'm now looking for a pendulous movement using a similar format so I can run this command to 
simulate the action of shuffling a card deck:

```
shuffleCard = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.pendulous);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the common rotation movement, but I set the pivotX and pivotY to a distant center, and reducing toDegrees to 20:

pendulous.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="20"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="150%"
        android:duration="600"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"/> 
</set>
```